# How to use bitshift operator in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to get the first 4 bits of a `byte` number, as another number. So I wrote something like this:

```
byte b = (byte)0xF4;
byte b1 = b >>> 4;
```

Why is the second statement not allowed in Java?

Edit:

I made changes as written in answer, it is leads to answer 0xFF, but 0x0F was expected;

Then I tried to present values in binary and noticed:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(0xF1));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString((byte)0xF1));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString((byte)0xF1 >>> 4));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(0xF1 >>> 4));
```

Output:

```
11110001
11111111111111111111111111110001
11111111111111111111111111111111
1111
```

It is simply that 0xF1 and (byte)0xF1 are different numbers. And operator (>>>) in one case add zeroes and units in other.

So I need to assign 0xF4 to byte b (which is signed), like it is unsigned byte, then make bit shift and receive 0x0F as result.

Comment: Is there a compile error? What does it say?

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `>>>` (and other binary operators) promotes the operands to at least `int` (as described in [JLS Sec 15.19](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19)). In this case, they are promoted to *exactly* `int`, and the result is then `int`, since the promoted type of the left-hand operand is `int`.

You need to cast explicitly back to `byte`:

```
byte b1 = (byte) (b >>> 4);
```

or use a compound assignment (which implicitly casts for you):

```
byte b1 = b; b >>>= 4;
```